# How can i record video using eye tracking technology and generate a heat maps?

Tags: android-studio, heatmap, eye-tracking

I want to develop an android application that record a video with eye tracking to generate a heat map. is there a way to do this in android studio?

Comment: The answer is yes, but it won't necessarily be easy.

Comment: do you know any library or tricks that is helpful?